# fetch Boolean values from core data

Tags: swift, core-data, boolean, fetch, option-type

In my swift code below the goal is to fetch a series of Boolean values. It should fetch multiple values. Something along the lines of false, false, true etc. Right now I am having issues in my base class on if let imageData = info[imageNo].bool causing a runtime error stating .bool is not a optional value. In my core data database the entity is called OnOff and the attribute is bool which a Boolean value. How can I fix my code to fetch the boolean values?

Base Class

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
func getBool(imageNo:Int) {
   // first check the array bounds
   let info = helpBool.shareInstance.fetchBool()
    
    print("image count is", info.count)
   if info.count > imageNo {
       
       // check if the data is available
       if let imageData = info[imageNo].bool
        {
      print(imageData)
           
       } else {
           // no data
           print("data is empty Textss")
       }
   } else {
       // image number is greater than array bounds
       print("you are asking out of bounds")
   }
}
```

Helper Class

```
       class helpBool: UIViewController{

static let shareInstance = helpBool()
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext





func fetchBool() -> [OnOff] {
    
  
    var fetchingImage = [OnOff]()
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "OnOff")
    
    do {
        
        fetchingImage = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [OnOff]
    } catch {
        print("Error while fetching the image")
    }
    
    return fetchingImage
}
}
```

Comment: You code would be much easier to read if  properly indented.

Comment: You can just cast the data type after fetch records from coredata.

Comment: @NarendraMistri can you show me how to do that?

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.